# Tag merge / synonym request: [degrees] -> [degree]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge [degrees](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/degrees) (4 questions) into [degree](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/degree) (20 questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, thanks for bringing the tags to our attention.